# Statamic V2: [InvalidArgumentException] Driver [] not supported

Tags: php, filesystems, driver, config, statamic

This is my statamic 2 project. I'm not sure about the root for this error. When ever I run 'php please' command I got the driver not supported error as you can see in the attached photos.

[php please command results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y540S.png)

[php please command results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaMOQ.png)

I also attached the error logs after i run the command:-

```
[2021-02-02 15:18:44] dev.ERROR: InvalidArgumentException: Driver [] not supported. in C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager.php:109
    Stack trace: 
    #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager.php(85): Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager->resolve('local')
    #1 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager.php(74): Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager->get('local')
    #2 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\core\API\Folder.php(38): Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager->disk('local')
    #3 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\core\API\Folder.php(50): Statamic\API\Folder::disk()
    #4 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\core\Providers\AddonServiceProvider.php(73): Statamic\API\Folder::__callStatic('getFolders', Array)
    #5 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\core\Providers\AddonServiceProvider.php(35): Statamic\Providers\AddonServiceProvider->findAddonFiles()
    #6 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(531): Statamic\Providers\AddonServiceProvider->register()
    #7 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php(74): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->register(Object(Statamic\Providers\AddonServiceProvider))
    #8 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(507): Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load(Array)
    #9 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerConfiguredProviders()
    #10 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders->bootstrap(Object(Statamic\Application))
    #11 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(208): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
    #12 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\core\Console\Kernel.php(76): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
    #13 C:\MAMP\htdocs\statamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(105): Statamic\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
    #14 C:\MAMP\htdocs\please(48): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #15 {main}
```

Attached is the command where I check the version of php, npm and statamic. All have been installed but why driver not supported?
[php, npm and statamic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Oc2.png)

[this is the debug mode with error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jleIl.png)

What is the solution so I can serve my project using 'php please serve' command ??

Comment: Please do not post images of text/errors, it's cumbersome for people to answer such questions. Please update your question with the content of the image instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If running `php please cache:clear` does not help, in my case deleting the Statamic bootstrap cache files helped:

- `statamic/bootstrap/cache/config.php`
- `statamic/bootstrap/cache/services.json`